# How can I change the size of images inside a p-galleria of PrimeNG?

Tags: gallery, primeng

I have a problem while using a `p-galleria` of PrimeNG with angular6.
The images inside it are coming with an automatically size and I don't have any idea how to change their size.

Hence I use a  `panelWidth` or `panelHeight` : it changes the panel but not the images inside it.

Any answer will help my, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with "frameWidth" and "frameHeight".

Example:

```
 <p-galleria [images]="images" panelWidth="573" panelHeight="430" [frameWidth]="120" [frameHeight]="80"></p-galleria>
```

I hope it will be usefull to somebody.